# Two CPUs as a single system

Tags: cpu, operating-systems

I don't know whether this is a foolish question or not. Is there a way to make two separate dual-core systems to run as a single quad-core system under a single operating system?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could, but it wouldn't make any sense. With the two systems having such massive latency between them and no hardware mechanisms for fast memory coherence, it wouldn't make sense to try to combine them in that way.

You can't use another person to let your brain control two more arms. You have to let their brain control their arms because your brain is too "far" from the arms to control them effectively.

Comment: What about something like [MOSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSIX)? While this type of environment does not support a single process using two nodes, it provides *some* of the advantages of SMP/single system image.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Yep, that's about the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Possible but not easy... I think this question and answers from [this link will be helpful to you](https://serverfault.com/questions/415003/how-does-one-cluster-multiple-machines-to-act-as-one-to-run-multiple-virtual-mac).

It would be easier to get a motherboard that supports the CPU's in question and has dual CPU ports but again its an expensive route, esp considering the cost of quad core machines nowadays.